# unexpected re.sub behavior

Tags: python, regex

I defined

```
s='f(x) has an occ of x but no y'
def italicize_math(line):
    p="(\W|^)(x|y|z|f|g|h)(\W|$)"
    repl=r"\1<i>\2</i>\3"
    return re.sub(p,repl,line)
```

and made the following call:

```
print(italicize_math(s)
```

The result is

```
'<i>f</i>(x) has an occ of <i>x</i> but no <i>y</i>'
```

which is not what I expected. I wanted this instead:

```
'<i>f</i>(<i>x</i>) has an occ of <i>x</i> but no <i>y</i>'
```

Can anyone tell me why the first occurence of x was not enclosed in inside the "i" tags?

Comment: The solutions I got were pretty good, but now I realise I need something more powerful as word boundaries as afforded by \b are not restrictive enough. I would like 4x to be converted to 4<i>x</i>. In other words the presence of 4 next to x should be a boundary. I will look at lookahead assertions.

Comment: Thanks to the leads below I found out that p='(?<![A-Za-z])([xyzfgh])(?![A-Za-z])' and repl='<i>\1</i>' suited my needs

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be trying to match non-alphanumeric characters (`\W`) when you really want a word boundary (`\b`):

```
>>> p=r"(\b)(x|y|z|f|g|h)(\b)"
>>> re.sub(p,repl,s)
'<i>f</i>(<i>x</i>) has an occ of <i>x</i> but no <i>y</i>'
```

Of course, `(` *is* non alpha-numeric -- The reason your inner content doesn't match is because `\W` consumes a character in the match.  so with a string like `'f(x)'`, you match the `(` when you match `f`.  Since `(` was already matched, it won't match *again* when you try to match `x`.  By contrast, word boundaries don't consume any characters.

Answer (score 3):

Because the group construct is matching the position at the beginning of the string first and `x` would overlap the previous match. Also, the first and third groups are redundant since they can be replaced by word boundaries; and you can make use of a character class to combine letters.

```
p = r'\b([fghxyz])\b'
repl = r'<i>\1</i>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Like previous answer mention, its because the `(` char being consume when matching `f` thus cause subsequent `x` to fail the match.

beside replace with word boundary `\b`, you could also use lookahead regex which just do a peek and won't consume anything match inside the lookahead. Since it didn't consume anything, you don't need the `\3` either

```
p=r"(\W|^)(x|y|z|f|g|h)(?=\W|$)"
repl=r"\1<i>\2</i>"
re.sub(p,repl,line)
```